# How to get secret from Google Secrets Manager using Serverless?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, serverless, serverless-framework, google-secret-manager

Using Serverless and AWS it's possible to load secrets from AWS SSM using:

```
environment:
  KEY: ${ssm(raw):/aws/reference/secretsmanager/prod/KEY}
```

Is there something equivalent available for Google Secrets Manager? Tried looking into Serverless documentation but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Do you use Google Cloud or AWS runtime environment?

Comment: Migrating to Google Cloud from AWS

Comment: Do you want to use secrets stored in secret manager in Cloud Functions? That's your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Serverless Google Cloud Functions plugin is actually poorly documented.

NO, You don't need to write your own plugin for that.

Serverless Google Cloud Functions does accept references to Secrets Manager out of the box and secrets are exposed as environment variables to your Cloud Functions!

If you just look into the code itself https://github.com/serverless/serverless-google-cloudfunctions/blob/4e59429ad2857cbc8d95ce70db6b41bed76b67ad/provider/googleProvider.js#L160

Notice the `functions` schema accepts a property named `secrets`. The implementation would look something like this:

```
functions:
  my-function:
    handler:  MyFunction
    memorySize: 128
    secrets:
      SendgridAccessToken:
        secret: SENDGRID_ACCESS_TOKEN
        version: latest
    events:
      - event:
          eventType: providers/cloud.pubsub/eventTypes/topic.publish
          resource: ${self:custom.params.EventBus}
```

Hope this is what you were looking for!